# Amplitude of steady current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

In the following circuit, the AC source is an ideal voltage source. Then what is the amplitude of the steady state current through the inductor at resonance .

[image]

Where V =V$_0$sin$\omega t$

According to me at steady state capacitor will act as infinite resistance and inductor will as negligible resistance . So the equivalent resistance should be R .

Hence the amplitude current should be V$_0$/R

But the answer given as V$_0$$\sqrt \frac {C}{L}$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Steady state is not the same thing as DC!

Comment: @RazimanT.V. Then whats the difference

Comment: @JohnRennie according to that I have posted my attempt

Comment: Showing your attempt is only half of the requirement.

Comment: @sammygerbil then what is the other half